# Confused with this output

Tags: java, string

The output for the code below is 3. Can anyone explain why is it 3? I can't understand.

```
public static void main(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  str = "Welcome";
    int ctr = 0;

    for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++) {
        if("aeiou".indexOf(str.charAt(i))!=-1) {
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ctr);
}
```

Comment: it looks like you need a [rubber_duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: What value are you expecting?  What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: well there are 3 vowels in `Welcome`...

Comment: No I'm asking can you explain why the output is 3 I don't get it in my opinion it is supposed to be 0.

Comment: Your braces and indentation are misaligned and confusing.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be zero? And see Reimeus' comment.

Comment: It iterates through `Welcome`, for each `char` there's a check whether it contains `aeiou` (`"aeiou".indexOf(str.charAt(i))!=-1`), if yes, `ctr++`. `ctr == 3`, since `Welcome` contains 3 vowels.

Comment: The code is 100% obvious.  it counts vowels in a word.  As mentioned by others "wElcOmE" has three vowels.

Comment: Oh ok now I get it thanks guys

Comment: why do you create a scanner?

Comment: Your program counts the number of vowels in the user input string.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this code together.

```
 for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
            if("aeiou".indexOf(str.charAt(i))!=-1)
              ctr++;
```

- `i=0 -> str.charAt(0) = 'W'` 
  There is not element in "eaiou" with value 'W' so `indexOf` returns `-1`. ctr=0;
- `i=1 -> str.charAt(1) = 'e'` 
  'e' is an element of "eaiou"  so `indexOf` returns `1`. ctr=1;
- `i=2 -> str.charAt(2) = 'l'` 
  There is not element in "eaiou" with value 'l' so `indexOf` returns `-1`. ctr=1;
- `i=3 -> str.charAt(3) = 'c'` 
  There is not element in "eaiou" with value 'c' so `indexOf` returns `-1`. ctr=1;
- `i=4 -> str.charAt(4) = 'o'` 
  'o' is an element of "eaiou"  so `indexOf` return `3`. ctr=2;
- `i=5 -> str.charAt(5) = 'm'` 
  There is not element in "eaiou" with value 'm' so `indexOf` returns `-1`. ctr=2;
- `i=6 -> str.charAt(6) = 'e'` 
  'o' is an element of "eaiou"  so `indexOf` returns `1`. ctr=3;

The final value is 3. The number of vowels in "Welcome"

Comment: Thanks guys you've really helped me

Comment: On another note is there any reason why I'm being downvoted? I can't understand and too many downvotes will prevent me from asking more questions

Comment: Users here can be sticklers for rules, which I can understand might make you a bit hesitant to post again, but following those rules helps the site to be more useful to the masses, rather than just for your specific issue. Try reading through the FAQs on writing a good question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites